# RGB colour correction of CCD camera images

Tags: image-quality, image-processing, image-manipulation

I've developed an application which is able to communicate directly with a CCD camera (unbranded and obscure) and I'm able to capture and store the image from this camera.

When the image is first captured, the byte order sequence for RGB data is sequential (RRRGGGBBB) so I correct this by simply interleaving the values. When this is done, the image colours are inverted. To fix this step I simply subtract the pixel values from 255.

At this stage, I have an image which closely resembles what is scanned, except for banding of RGB colours around the edges of what is being scanned. If you zoom in on the image I've attached, you will notice red/green/blue lines around the edges of the strips; most prominently around the 2D barcode.

[image: CCD camera result]

I have two questions pertaining to this issue:

1. Could anyone elaborate on the cause of this issue? Would it be a case of chromatic aberration? or something different that may often be observed in low quality CCD cameras?
2. What techniques may exist to combat this issue (which should be executable in real-time on a kiosk type hardware.

---

Edit 1: Included full image
[image]

Edit 2: Included original CCD image prior to colour inversion.
[image]

Comment: Is this a crop from a larger image? - this appears to be chromatic aberration yes, if this is not from the center of the image but the top/bottom/side then this is the cause.

Comment: Looks like chromatic aberration but I am seeing that it is present in all of the image. How are you getting your images ? Are you using Bayer filter ? Something can be wrong on the reconstruction step from color coded image. Additionally just an idea, if you are going to check only the QR codes, you can consider using grayscale images.

Comment: @DarkcatStudios Yes the image was cropped. I've attached the original image in the edit.

Comment: @SelimArikan I'm getting the RGB data from a CCD camera over a USB connection. This is all done programmatically. No filters are used, only 255-colourvalue to get the correct colours. The contents of the strips (not present) will be colour and that information is required, thus eliminating the use of greyscale.

Comment: @DarkcatStudios Is chromatic aberration a solved problem? do real-time solutions exist? or are they typically estimations?

Comment: @SelimArikan Apologies, I thought you were referring to post-processing filters at first. The CCD camera is completely unbranded and I have no information about its inner-workings, therefore I can't tell you what filter it uses.

Comment: I see that your image is quantized to 32 levels. And hue is shifted vertically not only close to the edges (ch. aberration) but in the whole image (http://i.imgur.com/Rcna2de.png). My opinion is, something is wrong with the camera's image processor or worse, CCD.

Comment: @SelimArikan Interesting; the entire processor and camera is built by a small firm which is no longer around. I know this has been compensated for in the past by other developers (no contact / no source code) so there must be a technique for this; my only issue is that I don't know what that technique would be.

Comment: This is not CA, this is just the artifact of the R, G and B sensors not sharing the same physical location. You should just adjust the R,G and B channels' location (in your image processing, that is, moving by pixels or subpixels) and you will have a composite image without errors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer vision that is unlikely to correspond to still photography.

Comment: In the beginning poster had doubts on CCD quality and chromatic aberration, finally we have concluded that issue is caused by the sensor or at the reconstruction step of the camera which both IMHO makes this question relevant.

Comment: Sorry, but I think it's very borderline and slightly on the wrong side of it. This appears to be for a barcode scanning application and I'm not really seeing how this will help photographers.

Comment: JoanneC: I actually have no interest in the barcode scanning, but in determining what was wrong with the CCD camera. I sought advice before coming here, and the question was directed here as it wasn't related enough to coding or programming. Thankfully I found somebody who could tell me that the issues of the camera which led to a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix this, you need to decompose your image to RGB channels separately. R and G channels are vertically shifted from B channel by 5 pixels each.
You need to align these channels vertically. For example I have shifted red channel 10 pixels and green channel 5 pixels from the blue channel.

Here is the result with comparison :

Shifted one [image: Shifted]

Corrected one [image: Corrected]

5 pixel value is only an assumption, you can improve this even more by using a calibration sheet.

Comment: Excellent Selim. Just the knowledge I needed, thank you. A quick question though; when you shift, what is left in the gaps? are the last pixels cycled to the start or are they replaced with black/white/alpha?

Comment: This is actually your preference. I have cropped the image as you can see from the bottom part of it. If you need to keep the original image size, you can choose to put black pixels to suit the background.

Comment: Yeah okay, I see! Thanks again for your help and explanations.